# Using popen() to open a program in command line?

Tags: c, xcode, command-line, popen

Is it possible to open a program using another program? For example:
I want to make a command line application in C that will prompt the user to type in the name of a program (lets say Microsoft Word.app), and that program will launch. Would I do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char programName[1000];
    printf("Type in the name of the program you would like to open: ");
    scanf("%s", programName);
    popen(programName);
}
```

However, popen() asks me for another char. How would I go about using popen() to open the program?

EDIT: The following code works!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char programName[1000];
    char app[100] = ".app";
    char openApp[100] = "open /Applications/";
    printf("Type in the name of the program you would like to open: ");
    scanf("%s", programName);
    strcat(openApp, programName);
    strcat(openApp, app);
    system(openApp);

}
```

Comment: Although your following code works, it has the potential to crash from running over the buffer in strcat, you are adding a possibly 1000 character array into a destination that can only hold a maximum of 100 characters.  char openApp[100]; must be at least char openApp[100 + 1000 + 20];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`popen` lets you launch a program and get a file descriptor to its input or output, much like `fopen` works for files. For instance, if you wanted to read the output of your program, you'd use `popen("program", "r")`. On the other hand, if you want to write to its input, you would use `popen("program", "w")`. Mac OS X also allows for `r+`, which lets you read the output and write to the input but this capability isn't standard and shouldn't be relied on for cross-platform code.

If you just want to launch a program, you might as well use the `system` function, which does that and waits until the program exits, at which point it returns the status code. `system` actually invokes the shell to work, so arguments will undergo expansion (environment variables, ~, etc).

**EDIT** Following your comment that `system("Microsoft Word.app")` doesn't work as you'd expect: there are several reasons for this, actually. Starting with the message you get: this is because what you wrote is equivalent to opening a terminal window and typing `Microsoft Word.app`. In other words, it tries to find a program called "Microsoft", then pass it the argument "Word.app". You would need to either quote the program name or escape spaces to have the shell understand it's a whole program name and not a program name then an argument: `system("Microsoft\ Word.app")`

Now, this should complain saying that the shell can't find the program "Microsoft Word.app", which is already a step forward.

This is because on Mac OS, `app` files aren't executable files: they're folders that the Finder displays as a single file. You can verify that by ctrl+clicking (or right-clicking) an app and selecting "Show package contents" (this will open the app folder). The actual executable for Microsoft Word.app must be somewhere along the path of `Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word`.

As you can see, this is getting kind of complex. Luckily enough, Apple provides the `open` executable, which can use a bunch of OS services to figure out those details. It allows to launch applications in the following fashion:

```
open -a Microsoft\ Word
```

This should launch Word. (Notice how you **still** need to escape the spaces.) In pure C code, that would get you something like this:

```
system("open -a Microsoft\\ Word");
```

If you choose to use Objective-C and Cocoa, however, there is a very simple way to open applications:

```
NSString* appName = @"Microsoft Word"; // no escape!
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appName];
```

`NSString` objects can be created from C string easily enough:

```
NSString* appName = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:programName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appName];
[appName release];
```

Comment: @zneak
When I do that, it says command not found. I'm assuming I did something wrong.
    Type in the name of the program you would like to open: Running…
    Microsoft Word.app
    sh: Microsoft: command not found

Comment: So if the application were only one word, I wouldnt need to escape the spaces?

Comment: @Mike, exactly. However, if you don't validate this input, you should make sure your users don't enter program names that could be harmful. If you're willing to go into Objective-C and use the Cocoa framework, you can easily launch programs with "complex" names (I've edited my answer to reflect that).

Comment: Thanks! Ill have to try making an interface for this app.

Comment: @Mike, you can use Cocoa for command-line programs too. You need to add the Cocoa framework to your project, and change the extension of your files to `.m` instead of `.c`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `system(3)` for this purpose.

The `popen(3)` function establishes a pipeline that can be read or written by the caller. But GUI applications do not use standard input and standard output, they connect to the graphical interface server, sometimes called the *["window server".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor)*  This server is already running and already has decided what its keyboard input will be, and it is always writing its output to the video device.

To start a ***.app*** you should actually run the *[open(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)* program, so try something like:

```
system("open /Applications/MacVim.app");
```

Comment: This ends up opening the application location in finder